# Excel formula for first day of previous month

Tags: excel, vba, datetime, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a formula for the first day of the previous month.
I'm using: `=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-1,1)`

It works today, but I don't think it will work in January, because the formula would then return the year as 2016, and I need it to return the previous year in that case.  Does anyone have a suggestion for how I can modify this so it will return Dec 1 of the previous year if the current date is sometime in January?

Comment: I would say nevermind, as I was wrong.  The formula I was using does appear to work.  I changed the date on my computer, but didn't refresh the formulas, which made it appear not to work.  I would however, be interested in different approaches to this formula.  Was reading a bit about the NSDate function.

Comment: Are you looking for this : `=DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+1,MONTH(TODAY())-13,1)`  ?

Answer (score 6):

You could try

```
=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)+1
```

Comment: That is way more elegant than what I used.  All that remains is to convert it back from the number of days since I think Jan 1 1900 or whatever base date Excel uses to the human format for dates.  I like your answer better.  Thanks!